# I can't reset the password through single user mode due to home directory encryption

Tags: 16.10

I forgot my password. So I can't access my laptop. I have tried single user mode for resetting the password but it's failed. Because while installing the Ubuntu OS I have set the home on encrypted. So I can't reset the password through single user mode. Is there any way to decrypt the home directory and reset the password.

Please help am I'm depression. Because somany datas are store in that laptop. Please.

Regrads
Vishnu PK

Comment: Which encryption did you use? http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/04/introducing-ecryptfs-recover-private.html

Comment: Sorry bro. I don't know which type of encryption is that. I only know that it is a home directory encryption. Am not familiar which that type of encryption. I set this encryption without more knowledge. Can you help me

Comment: DId you forgot your user password or the key to access your encrypted filesystem?

Comment: I have no more knowledge regarding the encryption. I set the encryption by mistake.so i don't no what the key. And also I for the user password.

Answer (score 0):

**Bad news**: There are no workarounds, no way to "recover", no secret backdoors, no "help" to be offered.

If you want the data, you MUST know the correct passphrase. That is encryption's sole purpose.

Sorry.

Comment: In linuxs there is no way to alive this issue. I am traped

Comment: The OS is not relevant. No OS should allow you to decrypt without the proper key, just as no lock should allow strangers to enter your home uninvited. You did make multiple new-user mistakes (selected feature you didn't really want, misunderstood the nature of encryption, forgot key, no backups, etc) and we hope the lessons you have learned will lead to a better experience next time.

Comment: While checking i got a doc based on this. Is this possible. https://www.howtogeek.com/116297/how-to-recover-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-ubuntu/

Comment: You are quite welcome to try it. I do not see how it could make things worse. However, be aware that those instructions still require your passphrase.